# Trying to write a custom module for loading only the child terms for each parent term ID in my content view

Tags: 9

I have a content view using Display Suite which has a teaser of some of my content. The content type has taxonomy references to the parent terms in my taxonomy vocabulary. And in the actual taxonomy vocabulary, I have a set of parent and child terms which looks like this.

```
**City #1**
Price #1
Price #2

**City #2**
Price #3
Price #4
```

So I've read many resources trying to tell me to try various community modules, or telling me to configure the view in a certain way, but since none of them have worked, I'm trying to write a custom module.

In my view, I have a filter criteria dropdown (after using 'Taxonomy term on node' relationship), and then I limit the terms to the parents (the cities) in the dropdown.

I also have another relationship, 'Parent,' which I relate to the 'Taxonomy term on node' relationship. And in the filter criteria, I use the 'parent' relationship.

So when I select the parents, it does load the parents and the cities, but it loads ALL of them (City #2 and its respective prices shows up when I select City #1).

Basically, all I need is to somehow hide all of the other cities and prices, and show only the respective parent and child terms for each city being selected.

Any ideas on where I could start, in terms of coding this?

Comment: That sounds like a regular Views case, I don't see the need for a custom module if your problem is figuring out what the database query is, since this is what Views do. Your filter seems to be not working, it's hard to say why without all the details. Can you include all the Filter and Relationship info in your question with some node and term examples?

Comment: I added only one detail I forgot, the 'parent' relationship, and also clarified my content type details. Everything else is basically configured as I described it. The cities are the parents in my example, the prices are the children terms. When I select each city, it loads all of the other cities and prices. It's not loading just the the individual child terms for each respective parent term.